# How to change MySite URL to HTTPS

Tags: user-profile, my-site, url, https

This shouldn't be hard, but ultimately is.

I only found references that I should [backup the existing MySite](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1967de0c-d2c9-45db-ad3e-c8c17b701b3f/changing-mysites-url-aam-mysites) and move it to another location. The MSDN documentation on [Configure My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx#configsettings) is pretty thin on changing the URL.

The only viable information I found so far is: [`UserProfileManager.MySiteHostUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.mysitehosturl.aspx) (gets or sets the URL for the current context). *Under User Profile Administration > Setup My Sites* I am also supposed to be able to change the My Site URL.

The problem is that none of these changes are persistent. I change the `MySitehostUrl` with PowerShell - the change is not persisted. I change the URL via CA, click OK, the URL is gone.

I initially set up MySites to not use HTTPS, I want to change that now. AAM is set up and HTTPS works perfectly, only the URL is still wrong.

**How to change the MySite Url from: `http://mysite.example.org` to `https://mysite.example.org`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you changed the My Site Host URL did you extend and map it to your original my site host or did you just add the binding in IIS and then change AAM? Change the web application and ensure that all of the dependancies are working as well as changing the setting in the User Profile Service Application.

Ensure that the URL you wish to use for the MySite Host URL is in the DEFAULT zone in the AAM Mapping.

Once that is done it should work just fine.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right with that. I only changed the IIS binding and added a certificate. So you're saying I should just extend the web app, then I should be able to change the URL?

Comment: Yes, the "right" way is to extend the web app and then handle the certificate on the new site.

Comment: I extended the Web Application now, still I cannot change the MySite Host URL. Again: It is accessible via the URL - I'm talking about the `MySiteHostUrl`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.mysitehosturl.aspx - I believe this relates to the Host URL Setting in the UPS - changing it there has no effect either, it is just not saved.

Comment: Are you monitoring the ULS logs while you are changing the URL?

Comment: Good thinking. Nothing out of the ordinary. No exceptions.

Comment: Got it! I figured out the problem with trustworthy ILSpy. SharePoint internally calls `SPFarm.Local.AlternateUrlCollections.SerializeUrlForStorage(value);` with the newly supplied URL. The problem is that the method returns the *default* zone URL. In my case the default was HTTP, Intranet was HTTPS. I switched Default and Intranet around et voilá. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. If you could, you should update your answer so others may find it more quickly.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the second paragraph? Does it need further clarification?

Comment: You edited your own answer to include this paragraph one day after I asked you nicely for it. So no. I think it doesn't need further clarification.